# how can I read line by line insert into an array with special condition?

Tags: php, arrays, string

```
<b title="FunctionalCI">ApplicationSolution</b>::42<br/>
<ul class="treeview">
<li>Name = Sep11</li>
<li>Description = <div ></div></li>
<li>Organization = <a href="http://localhost/itop/web/pages/UI.php?operation=details&class=Organization&id=4&c[menu]=ConfigManagementOverview" title="Organization::4">test</a></li>
<li>Organization name =test</li>
<li>Business criticity = <span title="high">high</span></li>
<li>Move to production date = 2014-12-31</li>
<li>Contacts = </li>
<li>CIs = <a href="http://localhost/itop/web/pages/UI.php?operation=details&class=FunctionalCI&id=49&c[menu]=ConfigManagementOverview" title="Functional CI::49">Sep Console04</a>, 42 49, Sep11, Sep Console04<br/><a href="http://localhost/itop/web/pages/UI.php?operation=details&class=FunctionalCI&id=50&c[menu]=ConfigManagementOverview" title="Functional CI::50">Sep Console05</a>, 42 50, Sep11, Sep Console05<br/><a href="http://localhost/itop/web/pages/UI.php?operation=details&class=FunctionalCI&id=53&c[menu]=ConfigManagementOverview" title="Functional CI::53">Sep Engine CO04</a>, 42 53, Sep11, Sep Engine CO04</li>
<li>Business processes = <a href="http://localhost/itop/web/pages/UI.php?operation=details&class=BusinessProcess&id=44&c[menu]=ConfigManagementOverview" title="Business Process::44">Business Process</a>, 44 42, Business Process, Sep11</li>
<li>CI Type = Application Solution</li>
<li>Friendly name = Sep11</li>
</ul>
<b title="FunctionalCI">WebApplication</b>::49<br/>
<ul class="treeview">
<li>Name = Sep Console04</li>
<li>Organization = <a href="http://localhost/itop/web/pages/UI.php?operation=details&class=Organization&id=4&c[menu]=ConfigManagementOverview" title="Organization::4">test</a></li>
<li>Organization name = test</li>
<li>Business criticity = <span title="low">low</span></li>
<li>Move to production date = 2014-12-26</li>
<li>Contacts = </li>
<li>Application solutions = <a href="http://localhost/itop/web/pages/UI.php?operation=details&class=ApplicationSolution&id=42&c[menu]=ConfigManagementOverview" title="Application Solution::42">Sep11</a>, 42 49, Sep11, Sep Console04</li>
<li>CI Type = Web Application</li>
<li>Friendly name = Sep Console04</li>
</ul>
```

Hi every one , I am new in php programming . as you can see , I have the test.txt file.I want to read the test.txt file line by line in php , and then save the each line in a two dimensional array (like data[i][j]) . the row index i should be change `only when $line =="</ul>"`.

I wrote codes as follows to read the test.txt file :

```
$file = fopen("result.xml", "r");
if ($file)
{
while (!feof($file))
        {
            $line = fgets($file);
.....
}
}
```

I am confusing about how to control `row index i when "$line == "</ul>"`

 I really appreciate for your help in advance !
Thanks a lot !

Anwar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before of the while(!feof($file)), you need to define the $data array and $i.

```
$data = array();
$i=0;
$data[$i] = array();
```

That can all be done in one line, but it is separated into three here to make more sense.

Now, after you read the line, you see if it is </ul>. I would trim it - just in case it has whitespace. If it is </ul>, increment $i and create a new array.

```
if(trim($line) == '</ul>')
{
    $i++;
    $data[$i] = array();
}
```

Again, that can be a one-liner, but it is separated here for clarity.

Now you know $i, so add a new line to $data[$i]...

```
$data[$i][] = $line;
```

At the end, you can print_r($data) to see if it is what you want.

Comment: Hi Kainow,  thanks a lot for your instruction ! I will try to verify whether it works or not .

Comment: @kainow, yes , it works as I expect . Thanks a lot !

Comment: I added some lines as folows : libxml_use_internal_errors(true);$doc = new DOMDocument(); $doc->loadHTML($line);
     $record = $doc->getElementsByTagName('li');
     $data[$i][] = $record; But, I couldn't get the values of "<li>" tag. How can I modify the code to get the values of "<li>" tag , please ? ...thanks !